# How to build typed memory map of heap of C++ program

Tags: c++

Under assumption that reinterpret casts are not allowed, we can assume that each region of heap-allocated memory has some type and value.

So for each pointer at some breakpoint I want to know things about objects it points to:

- Type of allocated object
- If pointer points to array element, I want to know index in array.

**Possible solution**

Solution I'm thinking of now is to to log all `new` and `new []` calls. For each new call I need to log:

- Allocated Type
- Size of allocated object
- Number of elements for new []

(delete and delete[] should be traced too)

Currently the best idea I have is: 
Write regexp to find all new calls in source code and replace:

new T() with

```
template<class T, class... Args>
T* my_new(Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << "new Type: " << typeid(T).name() << " Size: " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// example
int *new_int = my_new<int>(12);
```

new T[n] with:

```
template<class T>
T* my_new_array(size_t n)
{
    std::cout << "new[N] N: " << n << " Type: " << typeid(T).name() << " Size: " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
    return new T[n];
}

// example
auto *int_vec = my_new_array<std::vector<int>>(12);
```

Is there a better solution? Ideally I don't want to rewrite source code.

I need this information in debugger, so for each pointer I can understand where it points to.  I.e. for some arbitrary address in memory I can know what lies there.

Comment: At the risk of spoiling the intellectual exercise.....for heaven's sake, WHY??

Comment: @Spencer I want to propagate this information to debugger. So for each pointer to dynamically allocated region of memory I can understand where it points to.  Currently it is impossible to understand in debugger whether the pointer is valid or not.

Comment: Just a note: C++ is not a regular language, and therefore I seriously doubt that a regular expression can parse all uses of `new`, without even taking into account that there may be a preprocessor involved...

Comment: @AlexP agree, that is why I'm now thinking of using libclang to parse source code and find `new` in AST.

Comment: How to put this politely...you want to generate a haystack to determine if a needle is threaded. This falls into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) category.

Comment: @Spencer Somewhat agree. What I really need is to build typed memory map. I will reformulate topic

Comment: The jerk comment: You sure you want to use `new` in the first place?

Comment: @user4581301 I reformulated the topic to address XY Problem. What I need is a more information about heap in debugger

Comment: In the real world, programmers replace one small part of the code at a time, not try and figure out where all the calls to `new[]` and do everything in one massive swoop.  Trying to fix everything at once with a magic template or macro is risky, at best.

Comment: I'm old, don't remember. Is `malloc()` banned in C++? Does C++ ban pointers to elements of arrays which are not allocated on the heap?

Comment: @AlexP malloc() is part of C. I'm assuming pure C++.   Sizes of stack-allocated arrays are known to debugger out of the box by debuginfo

Comment: You can replace new and delete. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: @KennyOstrom replacements are not typed. They return void *

Comment: Doesn't valgrind resolves this? (plus hundred things more)

Comment: Oh, I see, you want the types, not just logging some allocation. My mistake.

Comment: There are things like `std::vector`, that allocate large chunks of raw memory, then construct objects into it later as needed.

Comment: @Ped7g No, my understanding is that valgrind knows nothing about C++ types.